# Where does VSIDE store/cache extra source file search folders told by user?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I find such a weird problem. A screenshot shows this.

[image: VS2019 asks for custom source directory.]

Using Visual Studio 2019 v16.11,

- when debugging, I see a function named `_except_handler3` on the callstack.
- I double click the  `_except_handler3` item, VSIDE pops up "Find Source" dialog asking for file location of `d:\a01\_work\5\s\src\vctools\crt\vcruntime\src\eh\i386\exsup3.asm`.
- Hmm, it looks like this is a Microsoft internal source file, and I don't have it.
- I take the chance to try something wacky. From leaked windows NT5 source code, grab the a file with the same name [exsup3.asm](https://github.com/akinbicer/windows-nt5/blob/main/src/base/crts/crtw32/misc/i386/exsup3.asm), and place it into `D:\test\src123` and tell VSIDE to use it.
- VSIDE accepts it, and, not surprisingly, VSIDE can not display the ASM source code correctly, because that 20-year-old faking `exsup3.asm` probably does not match VC2019's `_except_handler3` machine code.

Now my question comes up: VSIDE seems to store/cache my `D:\test\src123` directory path somewhere in the system, so that each time [ I restart debugging my program and try to double click `_except_handler` ], VSIDE always asks me whether I need to use `D:\test\src123\exsup3.asm` as source code.

I try three ways to clear the "cache", but in vain.

(1) Delete .sln/.vcxproj and their whole folder from hard disk.

(2) Search registry node HKCU and HKLM, but find no appearance of `src123` .

(3) Delete whole `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_08fbc860` folder and see it re-created next time I start VSIDE.

By saying "in vain", I mean, VSIDE keeps asking me whether I want to use the source file `D:\test\src123\exsup3.asm` .

Then I'd like to ask, where on earth does VSIDE store my directory string `D:\test\src123` ?

Comment: Hi, if possible, could you please provide more info about the minimal code example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, please use this project file: https://github.com/chjfth/bookcode-mswin/tree/master/PAWIN4/24-EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION , and remember to use BuildConf "vs2019 Debug" instead of the default "Debug".